# ImportError: No module named pip.log -- in installation using pip

Tags: python, pip

I am working on Ubuntu 10.10 and I have installed pip using the following command

```
apt-get install python-pip
```

However when I try installing any package using pip I get the following error

```
ImportError: No module named pip.log
```

What has possibly gone wrong here?hon

Comment: What's your output when you run `which pip` ?  How does that compare to `which python` ?

Comment: yes they compare which pip gives /usr/bin/pip and which python give /usr/bin/python

Comment: I always advice people to avoid installing ANY python package using any other tool but `pip` or `easy_install`, because I have seen some linux distros messing with python packages. Try installing pip using any method describe here http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on debian squeezy(6.0) which default installation is python 2.6. To reproduce the problem:

1. Upgrade python to 2.7 from building the source code and installed it in /opt/python.
2. `wget bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` and run `get-pip.py`. The installtion should be successful.
3. run `pip` and the errors occur. `ImportError: No module named pip.log`.

The steps to solve the problem:

1. `ls -l /usr/bin/pip` find the old pip installation location.
2. `rm -rf pip` remove the old pip installation.
3. reinstall the `pip` with `get-pip.py`
4. relink the `/usr/bin/pip` to the new pip installation location which in my computer is `ln -s /opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py pip`