# Error running 'pip install': "ImportError: No module named pip"

Tags: python, macos, pip

OS: [Mac OS X 10.7.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Lion) (Lion) 
Python ver: 2.7.5

I have installed setuptools 1.0 with ez_setup.py from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools. 
Then I downloaded pip.1.4.1 pkg from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/1.4.1.

I ran (sudo) `python setup.py install` in [iTerm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITerm2), output:

```
running install
running bdist_egg running egg_info writing requirements to
pip.egg-info/requires.txt writing pip.egg-info/PKG-INFO writing
top-level names to pip.egg-info/top_level.txt writing dependency_links
to pip.egg-info/dependency_links.txt writing entry points to
pip.egg-info/entry_points.txt warning: manifest_maker: standard file
'setup.py' not found

reading manifest file 'pip.egg-info/SOURCES.txt' writing manifest file
'pip.egg-info/SOURCES.txt' installing library code to
build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg running install_lib warning:
install_lib: 'build/lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to
install

creating build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg creating
build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/EGG-INFO copying
pip.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying pip.egg-info/SOURCES.txt ->
build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/EGG-INFO copying
pip.egg-info/dependency_links.txt ->
build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/EGG-INFO copying
pip.egg-info/entry_points.txt ->
build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/EGG-INFO copying
pip.egg-info/not-zip-safe ->
build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/EGG-INFO copying
pip.egg-info/requires.txt ->
build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/EGG-INFO copying
pip.egg-info/top_level.txt ->
build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/EGG-INFO creating
'dist/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg' and adding
'build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg' to it removing
'build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg removing
'/Users/dl/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg'
(and everything under it) creating
/Users/dl/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg
Extracting pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg to
/Users/dl/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages pip 1.4.1 is
already the active version in easy-install.pth Installing pip script
to /Users/dl/Library/Python/2.7/bin Installing pip-2.7 script to
/Users/dl/Library/Python/2.7/bin

Installed
/Users/dl/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pip==1.4.1 Finished processing
dependencies for pip==1.4.1
```

Then I ran `pip install` and got the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.4.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 357, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2394, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2108, in load
ImportError: No module named pip
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: What happens when you run pip install from the terminal (not python interpreter)

Comment: The terminal shows a error like "Import Error: No module named pip"

Comment: I have counter the same question after update MacOSX. finally I found I setup pip failed. Reinstall pip and then fix it.

Comment: you could refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061039/importerror-no-module-named-pip-log-in-installation-using-pip?rq=1

Comment: Seems that will be not solution for You but I always try this command when I have some trouble with pip `python -m pip install <package>`

Comment: HEADS UP: Systems that use Python for the system itself ship it without `pip` for a reason. *Manually installing `pip` and changing packages of the system Python can break your system in the worst case!* Unless you are absolutely positively sure that you need `pip` for the system Python, you need a *separate* Python instance – such as a venv or separate installation – which should ship with `pip` automatically these days.

Comment: This has devolved into answers for both Linux and Windows. Isn't there a more canonical question (where answers for those platforms could go instead)?

Answer (score 385):

My solution for a Ubuntu machine:

For Python 3

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

For Python 2

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

Comment: the question is about installing on Mac.

Comment: On Arch I had to install python2-pip, python-pip pointed to python3

Comment: OMG thank you! I have a vagrant box spun up with python 3 and was wondering why pip commands where not working when I installed pip via 'sudo apt-get install python-pip'. These versioning changes (i.e. like php with homebrew) drive me crazy sometimes...

Comment: `sudo yum install -y python38-pip` worked! Thanks..

Comment: `Package python-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source However the following packages replace it: python3-pip
E: Package 'python-pip' has no installation candidate` and `E: Unable to locate package python2-pip` per Florian's suggestion

Answer (score 357):

With [macOS v10.15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina) (Catalina) and Homebrew 2.1.6, I was getting this error with Python 3.7. I just needed to run:

```
python3 -m ensurepip
```

Now `python3 -m pip` works for me.

Comment: In Ubuntu I get "ensurepip is disabled in Debian/Ubuntu for the system python".  
 I solved with `sudo apt install python3-pip`

Comment: Works also under Windows! After saying `pip install --upgrade pip` my pip was gone (because pip was uninstalled sucessfully but failed to reinstall because pip.exe was busy...).  `python -m ensurepip` brought back the default pip, from where I could take the correct upgrade path `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped me fix this issue on WIndows without reinstalling python.

Comment: The working command for me in windows was `python -m ensurepip`

Comment: worked on Ubuntu

Comment: This failed for me on Windows (`ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied`). Using an administrator prompt worked though.

Comment: Worked on Almalinux 9

Comment: You may get `/usr/bin/python: No module named ensurepip`

Answer (score 238):

On Mac, using [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) (executable `brew`) is a better option as **apt-get** is not available.

Command:

```
brew install python
```

In case you have both Python 2 and Python 3 installed on the machine:

```
python2.7 -m ensurepip --default-pip
```

simply should solve the issue.

If instead you are missing pip from Python 3 then simply change `python2.7` to `python3` in the command above.

Comment: Oh finally a working solution! Thanks!  I needed python3 on Mac (Mac OS X 10.13.4). After installing python with **Brew** `brew install python` the **pip** was not found: `python3 -m pip install redis` resulted in pip not found. Following your approach (python3 -m ...) did the trick.

Comment: I am having python2 and 3 on the same machine but for now I wanted to use Python3. Hence I had to modify the comment above to `sudo python3 -m pip install matplotlib` (I had to do this via sudo, otherwise some folder permission didnt work). (edited the answer correspondingly)

Comment: This worked for me, just remember to add a `sudo` at the beginning.

Comment: When running the second command I get:
"zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available"

Comment: @vicegax No, do not use `sudo` with pip. You should not be modifying OS Python installation with extra libraries. Learn to use `venv`

Answer (score 88):

For Windows:

```
python -m ensurepip
```

After activating your environment. Example: venv

```
(venv) PS D:\your path> d:\your path\venv\scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Sample of a result:

```
Collecting pip

  Using cached pip-21.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 MB)

Installing collected packages: pip

  Attempting uninstall: pip

    Found existing installation: pip 20.1.1

    Uninstalling pip-20.1.1:

      Successfully uninstalled pip-20.1.1

Successfully installed pip-21.3
```

Comment: Thanks **python -m ensurepip** saved my life. After Ubuntu upgrade (on production from 21 to 22), no more modules in my `venv` => **error 500**. Apache logs said : "no module named django". Also `PIP` seemed to be not installed. After **ensurepip** in my VENV , I just ran `pip install -r requirements.txt` (because `pip freeze` was returning an empty result) and all my modules went back. Site if live again. Thanks @Fethi Pounct. If you want to know what's **ensurepip** , have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html)

Answer (score 65):

After installing *ez_setup*, you should have `easy_install` available. To install `pip` just do:

```
easy_install pip
```

Comment: this only reinstalled pip on python3. how about fixing pip installation in python 2.7.x?

Comment: Works for Windows as well... Thanks!

Comment: What is "ez_setup"?

Comment: If you have multiple versions of python installed, you might want to target the install to the specific python version with something like `. "C:\Python\Python 3.8.6-64\python.exe" -m easy_install pip`.

Answer (score 33):

Run

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

Then run the following command in the folder where you downloaded: get-pip.py

```
python get-pip.py
```

Comment: This worked for me, but for python2, the according link is this: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py

Comment: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-20.04/

Comment: What is *pypa.io*? Is it reputable? The answer ought to address it, but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.

Answer (score 29):

Try to install `pip` through Python:

Please go to: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/

and download `get-pip.py`, and then run:

```
python get-pip.py
```

Comment: _Never_ just `sudo` npm/pip/gem & co _just to get it to work_ - it's insanely dangerous.

Comment: But why do you need this? Python3 comes with Pip since version 3.4

Answer (score 18):

On some kind of Linux, like distributions based on [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian), you might want to consider updating your '**apt-get**' first, in case you are installing *python-pip* through it.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This might help *apt-get* to update its indexes and locate the *python-pip* package.
After this, you might install pip like this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip (Python 2)
sudo apt-get install python3-pip (Python 3)
```

Comment: For some kinds of Linux.

Answer (score 13):

I encountered the same error with Python 3.8.6 on [macOS v11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Big_Sur) (Big Sur).

Whether I used `pip` or `pip3`, I'd get this error:

```
 File "/Users/marcelloromani/dev/<repository>/venv/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

It turns out my virtualenv was out of date.
This fixed the issue for me:

1. Remove the old virtualenv

   ```
   deactivate
   rm -rf venv
   ```
2. Initialise a new virtualenv

   ```
   virtualenv venv
   . venv/bin/activate
   ```
3. Install the new requirements then worked:

   ```
   pip install -r src/requirements.txt
   ```

Comment: Deactivating and reactivating worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: This was the trick for me as well. You can tell if the version you get when you run `python --version` is a different Major/Minor than what's in your `$VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/` directory.

Answer (score 10):

If you get "No module named pip" in [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29), try this:

```
python3 -m pip --version
```

Output:

```
/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip
```

And:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

It worked for me.

After successful installation, validate using

```
python3 -m pip --version
```

To upgrade to the latest pip version

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: when trying this I get `Both /lib/terminfo/w/wsvt25m and /usr/lib/terminfo/w/wsvt25m exist`, any idea? I am using Ubuntu under WSL2 (Windows)

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this same issue when I attempted to install the [Nova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStack#Compute_(Nova)) client (as root).

```
python  setup.py install
```

Output:

```
running install
/usr/bin/python: No module named pip
error: /usr/bin/python -m pip.__init__ install   'pbr>=0.5.21,<1.0' 'iso8601>=0.1.4' 'PrettyTable>=0.6,<0.8' 'requests>=1.1' 'simplejson>=2.0.9' 'six' 'Babel>=0.9.6' returned 1
```

I use [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)), so I worked around the issue with `sudo easy_install pip`.

```
brew search pip
```

Output:

```
aespipe        brew-pip    lesspipe    pipebench    pipemeter   spiped    pipeviewer

If you meant "pip" precisely:

Homebrew provides pip via: `brew install python`. However you will then
have two Pythons installed on your Mac, so alternatively you can:
    sudo easy_install pip
spencers-macbook-pro:python-novaclient
```

And:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

The commands should be similar if you use [MacPorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts).

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
python -m ensurepip --user
```

This if your [Mac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh) is not above [macOS v11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Big_Sur) (Big Sur) and you installed Python 3. I did this and I don't have any problems now. Back to the legacy version of 2.7 I guess.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/425192/i-am-trying-to-install-pip-on-terminal-and-i-always-get-this-error

Answer (score 7):

Try to re-install the pip
use curl command to download the get-pip.py file:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

if curl is not working then open this link :
[get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)

create a get-pip.py file in your directory
copy the code from this link and put it in the get-pip.py file and save the file in the same directory.
then run the command

```
python get-pip.py
```

Comment: pip not worked after doing that, with same error on win10.

Comment: worked for me on wsl. I had to run curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py for python 2.7

Answer (score 6):

**Python3**

```
curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Just replace the python version you want in the above commands

**For python 3.11 specific install**

```
curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.11
python3.11 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

**For python 3.10 specific install**

```
curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.10
python3.10 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

**For python2.7**

```
curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py | python2.7
python2.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Python2 is end of life

Comment: Updated with python3

Comment: Thanks! Pip has been included with Python 3 since version 3.4, by the way.

Answer (score 5):

Download:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

---

Then install pip:

```
py get-pip.py
```

---

Then install any module, such as [Biopython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biopython):

```
py -m pip install biopython
```

Answer (score 4):

I think none of the previous answers can fix your problem.

I was also confused by this problem once. You should manually install `pip` following the official guide [pip installation](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/installing/#install-pip) (which currently involves running [a single `get-pip.py` Python script](https://packaging.python.org/installing/#install-pip-setuptools-and-wheel)).

After that, just `pip install <your package>`. The error will be gone.

Comment: The OP didn't mention Django anywhere.

Comment: latest link for pip installation documentation as of april 2023 https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/

Answer (score 4):

I know this thread is old, but I just solved the problem for myself on OS X differently than described here.

**Basically I reinstalled Python 2.7 through brew, and it comes with pip.**

Install Xcode if not already:

```
xcode-select –install
```

Install Brew as described [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/211541/homebrew-for-os-x-easily-installs-desktop-apps-and-terminal-utilities/):

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then install Python through Brew:

```
brew install python
```

And you're done. In my case I just needed to install pyserial.

```
pip install pyserial
```

Comment: I had Xcode already installed. Did `ruby ...` and `brew ...`. When running `pip ...` I got `-bash: pip: command not found`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the issue `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'` when I created a new Python 3 virtual environment using the command

```
python3 -m venv ~/venv/ontology    ## << note: "python3" (problematic)
```

which is a command often suggested (here, elsewhere).  When I entered that venv, pip was nowhere to be found.

In the interim, since first using that command to create Python virtual environments, my system Python had upgraded (Arch Linux system updates) from Python 3.7.4 to Python 3.9.2.

The solution is to use the command

```
python -m venv <your_venv>  ## e.g. python -m ~/venv/ontology
```

When I did that (`python -m ...` not `python3 -m ...`), that venv now contained `pip` ...

To upgrade `pip` within that venv, use

```
<your_venv_path>/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip

## e.g.
## /home/victoria/venv/ontology/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: fastest solution. thanks

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded `pip` binaries from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

It is very likely that the pip package was unsuccessfully updated.
You need to remove and recreate the virtual environment.

Deactivate and remove the virtual environment:

```
deactivate
rm -rf [virtual_environment_name]
```

Create a new one

```
python -m venv venv_name
```

Activate it

```
source ./venv_name/Scripts/activate
```

Install the package you want:

```
pip install [package_name]
```

Answer (score 2):

In a terminal, try this:

```
ls -lA /usr/local/bin | grep pip
```

In my case I get:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root  root      284 Сен 13 16:20 pip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root  root      204 Окт 27 16:37 pip2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root  root      204 Окт 27 16:37 pip2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root  root      292 Сен 13 16:20 pip-3.4
```

So `pip2` or `pip2.7` in my case works, and pip.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Debian, but this solution can also be applied for Ubuntu.

1. Usually, pip comes with python by default, in order to check if pip is installed in your system run.

> ```
> python -m pip --version
> ```

2. If pip is not there, install it using Aptitude Linux Package Manager,

> ```
> # For Python 2
> sudo apt install python-pip
>
> # For Python 3
> sudo apt install python3-venv python3-pip
> ```

3. I wouldn't use the `get-pip.py` script in Debian/Ubuntu, because in the documentation page mentions the following.

> Be cautious if you are using a Python install that is managed by your operating system or another package manager. get-pip.py does not coordinate with those tools, and may leave your system in an inconsistent state.

Sources [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#install-pip) and [there](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-linux-tools/#debian-ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minimal set of instructions for upgrading to Python 3 using [MacPorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts):

```
sudo port install py37-pip
sudo port select --set pip pip37
sudo port select --set pip3 pip37
pip install numpy, scipy, matplotlib
```

I ran some old code and it works again after this upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error on [Windows 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_11), so the main problem was on executing the *pip* command without administrator permissions, so open up your terminal with administrator permissions and then execute the *pip* command again.

Comment: Not recommended. You can pass `--user` flag to pip

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar error on Linux by setting PYTHONPATH to the site-packages location. This was after running `python get-pip.py --prefix /home/chet/pip`.

```
[chet@rhel1 ~]$ ~/pip/bin/pip -V

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chet/pip/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: No module named pip

[chet@rhel1 ~]$ export PYTHONPATH=/home/chet/pip/lib/python2.6/site-packages

[chet@rhel1 ~]$ ~/pip/bin/pip -V

pip 9.0.1 from /home/chet/pip/lib/python2.6/site-packages (python 2.6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested below for Linux:

You can directly download pip from https://pypi.org/simple/pip/,
untar, and use directly with your latest Python installation.

```
tar -xvf  pip-0.2.tar.gz
cd pip-0.2
```

Check for the contents:

```
ls
```

Output:

```
docs  pip.egg-info  pip-log.txt  pip.py  PKG-INFO  regen-docs  scripts  setup.cfg  setup.py  tests
```

Execute directly:

```
python pip.py --help
```

Output:

```
Usage: pip.py COMMAND [OPTIONS]

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -E DIR, --environment=DIR
                        virtualenv environment to run pip in (either give the
                        interpreter or the environment base directory)
  -v, --verbose         Give more output
  -q, --quiet           Give less output
  --log=FILENAME        Log file where a complete (maximum verbosity) record
                        will be kept
  --proxy=PROXY         Specify a proxy in the form
                        user:passwd@proxy.server:port. Note that the
                        user:password@ is optional and required only if you
                        are behind an authenticated proxy.  If you provide
                        user@proxy.server:port then you will be prompted for a
                        password.
  --timeout=SECONDS     Set the socket timeout (default 15 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice on this URL, to rename the *python39._pth* file. That solved the issue

https://michlstechblog.info/blog/python-install-python-with-pip-on-windows-by-the-embeddable-zip-file/#more-5606

```
ren python39._pth python39._pth.save
```

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to replace `pip` with `pip3` so I ended up running the command as follows: `pip3 install matplotlib`

Comment: Ideally, you use `python3 -m pip` instead of an alias

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with `virtualenv` that had `python3.8` while installing dependencies from `requirements.txt` file. I managed to get it to work by activating the `virtualenv` and then running the command `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt` and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

My Python version is 3.7.3, and this command worked:

`python3.7 -m pip install requests`

[Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library - for retrieving data from web APIs.

This runs the pip module and asks it to find the requests library on [pypi.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Package_Index) (the Python Package Index) and install it in your local system so that it becomes available for you to import.

Comment: which results in the same error as the original question "No module named PIP"

Answer (score -3):

For Windows:

If `pip` is not available when Python is downloaded: run the command

`python get-pip.py`

Comment: `FileNotFound: get-pip.py`