# how to use python2.7 pip instead of default pip

Tags: python, linux, django, centos, pip

I just installed python 2.7 and also pip to the 2.7 site package.

When I get the version with:

```
pip -V
```

It shows:

```
pip 1.3.1 from /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (python 2.6)
```

How do I use the 2.7 version of pip located at:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Answer (score 176, accepted):

There should be a binary called "pip2.7" installed at some location included within your $PATH variable.

You can find that out by typing

```
which pip2.7
```

This should print something like '/usr/local/bin/pip2.7' to your stdout. If it does not print anything like this, it is not installed. In that case, install it by running

```
$ wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py
$ sudo python2.7 get-pip.py
```

Now, you should be all set, and

```
which pip2.7
```

should return the correct output.

Comment: How would we uninstall the pip2.7 installed this way?

Comment: @personjerry You can simply run `pip2.7 uninstall pip` in order to have pip uninstall itself.

Comment: in fact 
<code>sudo curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python2.7 </code>
is more appropriate

Comment: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/2.7/get-pip.py
worked. 

And installed at:
$(HOME)/Library/Python/2.7/bin

Comment: Url changed to: `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py`

Comment: On Windows, use `where pip2.7` (because `which` is a linux command).

Comment: `ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.`

Answer (score 55):

An alternative is to call the `pip` module by using python2.7, as below:

```
python2.7 -m pip <commands>
```

For example, you could run `python2.7 -m pip install <package>` to install your favorite python modules. Here is a reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50017310/4256346.

In case the pip module has not yet been installed for this version of python, you can run the following:

```
python2.7 -m ensurepip
```

Running this command will "bootstrap the pip installer". Note that running this may require administrative privileges (i.e. `sudo`). Here is a reference: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ensurepip.html and another reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/46631019/4256346.

Comment: `/usr/bin/python2.7: No module named pip`

Comment: `python2.7 -m ensurepip`

Comment: yes I tried that as well. Just comes up with the same `ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found` issue.

Comment: Hmm... Sorry this is out of my depth.

Answer (score 1):

as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61699983/upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-04-killed-pip/61974430#61974430), this is what worked best for me:

```
sudo apt-get install python3 python3-pip python3-setuptools

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 10
```

Answer (score 1):

`pip` has now dropped support for python2, therefore you can't use python2 pip

You can't find `python2-pip` in `apt-get` anymore, and you won't get `pip` when installing python2 from source

You can still install python modules using `apt-get`. To install a python prepend ‘python-’ to the module name

```
apt-get install python-six  # install six
```