# pip install tensorflow-gpu installing in python 3.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, tensorflow

I am trying to install tensorflow for python 2.7 on Ubuntu 16. I am using pip install tensorflow-gpu and I get the following message in the terminal:

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-gpu in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from protobuf>=3.1.0->tensorflow-gpu)

When I ftry to `import tensorflow` It says `ImportError: No module named tensorflow` I am guessing since it is looking in the python 2.7 packages.

Shouldn't it be looking in python 2.7 dist-packges?

Comment: Do you have a program called `pip2.7` that you can run to install the package?

Comment: There is a pip in my 2.7 dist-packages

Comment: You might need to use a different command to install PIP packages for Python 2.7 (e.g. `pip2.7 install tensorflow-gpu`). See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26267333/3574081) for more suggestions.

Comment: It is no longer looking at the 3.5 dist-packages but still doesn't work

Comment: Did you try installing in a virtualenv? The tensorflow website has instructions for that, and that will be much easier to get working than messing with your system's python and pip.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use anaconda and run the following command

`conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu`

- Anaconda will make your life easier... hope this helps
  This will also install the `cuda toolkit` and `cudnn` for you and you are good to go