# how to Install Pip under /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages in Linux

Tags: python, linux, installation, pip

I have two version of Python in my Linux system
/usr/bin/python2.6
/usr/local/bin/python2.7

I want to install pip under python2.7 but it is getting automatically installed under /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages instead of /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages.

```
**[root@sandbox site-packages]# which pip
/usr/bin/pip
[root@sandbox site-packages]# pip -V
pip 7.1.0 from /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (python 2.6)**
```

I think there is some issue with two version of python present in Linux.
How can i forcibly install pip under python2.7 ?

Can someone help me resolve this  ?

Comment: Did you try removing `pip` completely, updating your repositories, and reinstalling it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use python2.7 pip instead of default pip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266437/how-to-use-python2-7-pip-instead-of-default-pip)

Comment: @Wintro - Yes i tried to remove pip using following comand:                  sudo yum remove python-pip  and am installing pip using this command:sudo yum  install python-pip python-dev build-essential but it is getting installed under python2.6

Comment: @Sergei : i tried to follow step in the link mentioned but i am getting following error: sudo /usr/local/bin/python2.7 get-pip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 20061, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 194, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
/the/path/to/your/python2.7 -m pip install *your-packages*
```

Regards,
Ed

Comment: Or try `sudo /usr/bin/python -m easy_install <package-name>` in case you are missing `pip`

Comment: What if they (easy_install and pip) are both missing?