# Import Error: Missing required dependencies ['numpy'] while ruuning task from task scheduler

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I am running a small piece of code in pycharm using python 2.7 and is running smoothly.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

print("Ok! its running")
```

Then i created .bat file named "test.bat" to run my program

But when i scheduled my task in task scheduler, I am getting error

```
Import Error:"Missing reuirment dependencies ['numpy']
```

I have python 2 and python 3 both in my laptop in D and C drives respectively.
the program runs successfully when i give python 3 path in task scheduler but not with python 2.7.
Why?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that its using your default pip instead of the pip of Python 2. You can check running the following command:

```
pip --version
```

Which return which pip its using as you can see for me its using pip for Python 3 by default:

```
pip 22.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

You should use the following command for Python 2:

```
python2.7 -m pip <commands>
```

You can finde more info here [how to use python2.7 pip instead of default pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266437/how-to-use-python2-7-pip-instead-of-default-pip)

Comment: Thanks, but it wasn't the problem. I found the solution, soon i will be posting it