# Installing pip on macOS does not work (anymore)

Tags: python, macos, pip, easy-install

I followed online instructions on how to install `pip` on macOS (for example [this](https://ahmadawais.com/install-pip-macos-os-x-python/), [this](http://softwaretester.info/install-and-upgrade-pip-on-mac-os-x/), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39256229/1971013)).

I all seems to simple, but it's not working for me.

My `python --version` is 2.7.10.

When I run `sudo easy_install pip` I get:

```
$ sudo easy_install pip
Password:
Searching for pip
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for pip
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')
```

Any idea how I can fix or work around this?

Comment: `sudo` and `pip` in the same command seem like a bad idea on OSX. I'd rather keep the system-provided Python completely under the OS updater control, and would do _any_ development and pip-based installation in a `virtualenv` and/or on a brew-installed Python.

Comment: @9000 Thanks for the advice. I'm new to Python. I did install brew during my attempts. How do I keep things under brew?

Comment: Just use `pip install` instead of `sudo pip install`. When in doubt, use `/usr/bin/pip`. Better yet, `brew install virtualenv`, [create a separate environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/) for each project, and install project-specific dependencies. This way projects never conflict with each other.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might have pip3 instead. Use it to upgrade pip.

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Even pip3 has the same issue.

Comment: after a day of headaches, worked like charm :)

Answer (score 6):

Use brew for Macs

`brew install python`

this will come with pip and both python2 and python3

instructions to bypass 2 python versions (if you want) are at https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installing/

otherwise, it'll just be "python3 <'program'>"

Here's how to install brew:
https://www.howtogeek.com/211541/homebrew-for-os-x-easily-installs-desktop-apps-and-terminal-utilities/

Comment: Tried that, but pip is still missing

Comment: Just try pip3 instead of pip. You can also use an alias of pip3 to pip using bash.

Answer (score 4):

easy_install has been deprecated. Use below commands instead.

1. `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`
2. `python get-pip.py`

[Source](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py)