# Discord debian module not found python3.6 and python2.7 installed

Tags: python, linux, debian, discord, discord.py

I am running a remote/dedicated Debian server over ssh and was hoping to get a discord bot running on it. I've run into a problem where python3 is telling me the 'discord' module can't be found despite making sure it has been installed countless times. Seen here:

[image]

It seems to me the module is clearly installed but python3 just can't find it. Any ideas?

I have tried several solutions from this site and others but none seem to fix it.

Comment: Your `pip3` and `python3` might not be looking in the same places.  What do you see for `pip3 show discord.py`?  There should be a `Location` field in the result.  Compare that to say `import csv; print(csv.__file__)` in your interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, it appears as though the locations are not exactly the same! One is looking in a 3.5 file and the other is in a 3.6 file. How can I go about correcting this? Here is the output https://i.gyazo.com/a3a4ad5e11a8d3932c69a56679f6afba.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make sure that you're using the `pip` associated with the `python` executable you're using by using the [`python -m` mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610001/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-m-switch).

```
python3 -m pip install discord
```

If you need to support multiple Python versions on a single machine (very common), I would recommend using something to manage the versions for you.  I use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) personally, but there are a few more out there.

Comment: /usr/local/bin/python3: No module named pip
I get this error when running that command, I have seen tons of people suggest this command but I cant seem to figure out how to actually use it
I tried following this guide, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363022/importerror-no-module-named-pip  but still no luck. Here's some output that might help you understand my issues https://i.gyazo.com/c2d8a6588048243d9155d3752aad0aa0.png

Comment: Try `python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade`? I haven't personally run into this though.

Comment: Looks like that did the trick! However I seem to be having some SSL issues with the discord install now. Looks like I need an SSL Module, any idea how I can get that installed? Here's the output: https://i.gyazo.com/1d9c653bb2467c97d1bc0c5224779b3d.png

Comment: @Plutoren Did you build Python yourself?  I think this happens when Python is built without `openssl`.  In that case you should probably abandon this Python installation, as you'll have to rebuild it to enable SSL.

Comment: I went ahead and deleted everything with the word python in it and got a totally fresh install of only python 3.6 and all my problems are solved. Python came pre-installed on my machine and I was worried that it was essential to the OS but it all worked out and nothing seems to have broken, thanks for the advice!