# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip' python and errors on all the package

Tags: python, pip, package

When I do install a python package from terminal and it is give me an error

```
pip install splinter
```

The error shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
  File "d:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Python\Scripts\pip3.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

I tried to install other package and it gives me the same error message.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363022/importerror-no-module-named-pip)

Comment: Which python version you are using ? See here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3

Comment: that does not solve my problem,'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I use the version python 3

Comment: Looks like you're on windows, Reinstall Python and make sure you add Python to your environment variables. Or if you know how to add environment variables then you can fix it even after installing

Comment: it is  works fine before and I don't know why it is doesn't work now