# pip ModuleNotFoundError - in runpy after path is set

Tags: python, pip, windows-10

I installed pip using 
    `$ python get-pip.py`

and I set PATH

```
  C:\Program Files\Python\Scripts
```

then I restarted the command prompt so that path would take effect. Then I run
      `$ pip`

I get this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\obj\Windows- 
Release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\runpy.py", line 193, in 
_run_module_as_main
  File "D:\obj\Windows- 
Release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\runpy.py", line 85, in 
_run_code
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in 
<module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip '
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. The Problem was I was using python binary and I set path myself, it caused some unreachable files. Now I reinstalled python with the installer. Now everything working fine. Everyone thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try: `$ pip -V`? Or `$ pip help`? Just guessing, but trying checking the version since pip probably requires an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Did you just run 'pip' or did you tried to install something with 'pip'?

A similar question and possible solutions you find here [ImportError: No module named pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363022/importerror-no-module-named-pip)

Comment: At first, I tried to install the virtualenv package, I got this error. then I ran pip alone which gives the same error.

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: The latest version I use, For your kind attention, I use python runnable, for which I set PATH too. Python can be accessed from everywhere, I checked it. pip alone troubles me.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming your using windows. You should just be able to add pip to your environment variables and granted you setting python in the environment variables also. It should work like something similar to below:

C:\Program Files\Python\Scripts or C:\Python34\Scripts or just C:\ Python34

Once those are in your environment variable path(which if your on windows 10 you get to by typing "Envi" and then the whole thing should come up edit the system environment variables. You should be able to put python in there). Then for pip you can find it hopefully within the **Scripts** folder in python and then put that in there also. Something like below:

C:\Python34\Scripts\pip

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I did what you said. But, it seems like the pip is reachable, but it fails to run.