# No Module named pip when running it

Tags: python

When I use pip3 I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

I tried to reinstall PIP but still reported this error, but I use `python3 -m ensurepip`

It told me to install Xcode command line

```
$ python3 -m ensurepip
$ xcode-select: Failed to locate 'python3.9', requesting installation of command line developer tools.
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by importing `pip`? I don't think I've seen anyone do that before

Comment: i want ```pip3 install aiohttp``` ，But it tells me ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'```

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood. Is this an error that you get when you run pip? in that case, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56896098/2550406) looks related and my guess is that you do need to install python first - like the xcode message tells you

Comment: I have been using Python for a long time, but I don't know why this error occurs

Comment: @futer_dream https://xkcd.com/1987/ - thats why ..

Comment: You could try running pip as a module? `python3 -m pip ...`

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I was trying to update the pip and it failed.
This always works for me:

- Download the script, from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py.
- Open a terminal/command prompt, cd to the folder containing the get-pip.py file and run:

```
python get-pip.py
```

font: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/

Answer (score 0):

Try to install python3.9 as suggested by the terminal.