# Install specific version of python in docker

Tags: python-3.x, docker, ubuntu

I try to run container from image `nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:22.08-tf2-py3`. But I have a problem.

The built docker-image contains python3.8. But I don't understand why I have this version of python in my docker-image. It is necessary to use python with version>=3.10 for correct work with libraries that I need. Version=3.8 is not explicitly specified in Dockerfile. When I try to install an another version:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common && add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && apt-get install -y python3.11
RUN python3.11 -m pip install --upgrade --no-cache -r requirements.txt
```

I get an error `/usr/bin/python3.11: No module named pip` during image building.

How can I correctly install specific version of python in my docker-image using Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

You got Python 3.11 alright but you are missing the PIP module. Add `python-pip` or `python3-pip` to the list of packages you install with `apt-get`.

Answer (score 0):

*This is regarding your problem with python3.11 pip and not the tensor version support*

Looking at the original python3.11 docker in [here](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/902e9de656bbd8c04d1cd3add264332d94ac9d40/3.11/bullseye/Dockerfile#L88) you should be able to use the bellow code.

```
# if this is called "PIP_VERSION", pip explodes with "ValueError: invalid truth value '<VERSION>'"
ENV PYTHON_PIP_VERSION 22.3
# https://github.com/docker-library/python/issues/365
ENV PYTHON_SETUPTOOLS_VERSION 65.5.0
# https://github.com/pypa/get-pip
ENV PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL https://github.com/pypa/get-pip/raw/66030fa03382b4914d4c4d0896961a0bdeeeb274/public/get-pip.py
ENV PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256 1e501cf004eac1b7eb1f97266d28f995ae835d30250bec7f8850562703067dc6

RUN set -eux; \
    \
    wget -O get-pip.py "$PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL"; \
    echo "$PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256 *get-pip.py" | sha256sum -c -; \
    \
    export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1; \
    \
    python get-pip.py \
        --disable-pip-version-check \
        --no-cache-dir \
        --no-compile \
        "pip==$PYTHON_PIP_VERSION" \
        "setuptools==$PYTHON_SETUPTOOLS_VERSION" \
    ; \
    rm -f get-pip.py; \
    \
    pip --version
```

I was able to install pip for my python3.11 on Fedora(outside Docker) using `python3 -m ensurepip` (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56896098/1454173))